# LaTeX is not able to recognize the $\square$ and $\Box$ symbols in article class, don't know why?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In the `beamer` class `\square` and `\Box` are working fine but in the `article` class they don't work. Any idea why? What can be done to make them work, do I need to use some special math symbols package?

Comment: Please what is your minimal working example or .log or other information to understand better?

Comment: The `beamer` class loads `amsmath` and `amssymb`, but `article` doesn't. Add `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\usepackage{amssymb}` to your document preamble.

Comment: @egreg Thanks worked like charm. I think you should move your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `beamer` class loads, by default, both `amsmath` and `amssymb` (unless these are explicitly disabled with the relevant class options).

The `\square` and `\Box` command are indeed provided by `amssymb` and loading this package would suffice for using them; however, if a document uses those symbols it is likely about mathematics and so `amsmath` is recommended as well.

Add

```latex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

to your document preamble.